# How to get passed and failed students using SQL?

Tags: sql, database

[image]

I am trying to get those students who passed the first exams will be eligible for 2nd-month exams.

For example student_ID = 1 and Exam_ID = 1 pass then he will be eligible for the exams of Exam_ID = 2.

But the students failed in Exam_ID = 2 will not be eligible for exam_ID = 3 and passed students shouldn't be shown in Exam_ID = 2.

For exam2 entry only those students should show who passed exam1 and in exam2 will be showing for exam3 entry those who are failed in exam2. Mean the students who passed exam1 but fail in exam2.

I am confused what query will be work for this.

I tried this:

```
select student_Id 
from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking 
where Office_Id = 1 
  and Class_Id = 1 
  and Exam_Id = 1 
  and Status = 'Pass'
```

but I am getting only student_id=1 and 2 while student_id=2 passed the exam1 then he shouldn't be shown in exam1. I mean the students shouldn't show who passed the exam1 and students shouldn't show for exam2 who passed exam2.

on running query I am getting this result.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem. Kindly help me in this scenario.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or SQLite?

Comment: you want a final list of Exam Id, Student Id? Or can you please update the question with your output.

Comment: I am using MSSQL not SQLite

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty actually I want the list of Student_Id according to Exam_Id.

See the example:

I am going to enter the marks of Office_Id=1 , Class_Id and Exam_Id=2
when I'll select the Exam_Id=2 then Student_Id of those will be showing to me who passed the Exam_Id=1 and who failed in Exam_Id=2. Those students shouldn't be show who passed exam_id=2 because these students are eligible for Exam_Id=3 and they passed Exam_Id=2 already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete answer to my query. I resolved after 5 days.

Select st.Student_Id, st.Student_Name,sm.Status,sm.Exam_Id from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking sm
inner join Tbl_Students st on st.Student_Id = sm.Student_Id
where sm.Office_Id = 1 and sm.Class_Id = 1 and sm.exam_id=2 and status='Fail' and Month(sm.Exam_Date)=08 and not exists(select * from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking as f where f.Student_Id=sm.Student_Id and f.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id  and f.Status = 'pass' and f.Exam_Id = (sm.Exam_Id+1))
and exists(select * from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking as f where f.Student_Id=sm.Student_Id and f.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id  and f.Status = 'Pass' and f.Exam_Id = (sm.Exam_Id-1))
and not exists(select * from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking as f where f.Student_Id=sm.Student_Id and f.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id  and f.Status = 'Pass' and f.Exam_Id = (sm.Exam_Id))
--AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl_StudentsExamMarking AS x WHERE x.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id AND x.Student_id = sm.Student_id AND x.Exam_Id = ( sm.Exam_Id ) AND x.[Status] = 'Fail')
Union
Select st.Student_Id, st.Student_Name,sm.Status,sm.Exam_Id  from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking sm
inner join Tbl_Students st on st.Student_Id = sm.Student_Id

where sm.Office_Id = 1 and sm.Class_Id = 1 and sm.exam_id=1 and status='Pass' and Month(sm.Exam_Date)=08

AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl_StudentsExamMarking AS x WHERE x.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id AND x.Student_id = sm.Student_id AND x.Exam_Id = ( sm.Exam_Id + 1 ) AND x.[Status] = 'Pass')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl_StudentsExamMarking AS x WHERE x.Office_Id = sm.Office_Id AND x.Student_id = sm.Student_id AND x.Exam_Id = ( sm.Exam_Id + 1 ) AND x.[Status] = 'Fail')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your challenge, try something like this:

```
-- Exam data mockup table and data.
DECLARE @ExamData TABLE ( Student_id INT, Class_id INT, Office_Id INT, Exam_Id INT, [Status] VARCHAR(4) );
INSERT INTO @ExamData ( Student_id, Class_id, Office_Id, Exam_Id, [Status] )
VALUES
    ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Pass' ),
    ( 2, 1, 1, 1, 'Pass' ),
    ( 9, 1, 1, 1, 'Fail' ),
    ( 10, 1, 1, 1, 'Fail' ),
    ( 1, 1, 1, 2, 'Pass' ),
    ( 2, 1, 1, 2, 'Fail' );

-- What exam has been passed?
DECLARE @PassedExamNo INT = 1;

-- Show students who have passed the specified exam and are eligible for the next.
-- Excludes:
--  Students who failed required exam.
--  Students who have already passed the next sequential exam.
--  Assumption: Exam ids are incremented by 1 for each sequential exam.

SELECT * FROM @ExamData AS e
WHERE
    Office_Id = 1
    AND Class_Id =1 
    AND Exam_Id = @PassedExamNo 
    AND [Status] = 'Pass'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM @ExamData AS x WHERE 
            x.Office_Id = e.Office_Id AND x.Student_id = e.Student_id AND x.Exam_Id = ( e.Exam_Id + 1 ) AND x.[Status] = 'Pass'
    );
```

Returns any student(s) who are eligible for the next exam:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
| Student_id | Class_id | Office_Id | Exam_Id | Status |
+------------+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
|          2 |        1 |         1 |       1 | Pass   |
+------------+----------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

You can run the above example in SSMS.

Comment: I not checked but today me going to check and run this query and I hope this work because I need to check those students who passed the prior class and eligible for next class and also those students should be show who are fail in prior class.

Comment: Dear, I checked and you worked good but I am not getting a valid result. when I run your query. You can see the result in this picture: https://ibb.co/vJ4S0rt

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table with itself and filter each join for the specific exam_id.

For example (You will need to replace @students with your table name):
In the following I make a subquery for exam_id = 1, a second subquery for exam_id = 2 and a third subquery for exam_id =3.
This gives you a "new table" that you then can filter.

```
SELECT
    E1.studentid,
    E1.Status AS [Status_exam2],
    E2.Status AS Status_exam2,
    E3.Status AS Status_exam3
FROM
(
    -- The first exam_id as the main table as normally all students will do the first exam
    SELECT *
    FROM @students
    Where exam_id = 1
) E1
LEFT JOIN
(
    -- Left join with the second selection as maybe not all patients already did the 
    -- second exam    
    SELECT *
    FROM @students
    Where exam_id = 2
) E2 ON E1.studentid = E2.studentid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @students
    Where exam_id = 3
) E3 ON E1.studentid = E3.studentid
```

With your example this gives the following output:
[image: Output of the upper SQL]

This "new" table, you can filter:
For example:

1. Patients passed exam_id1 but did not do the second or failed the second one
   Add the following at the end of the above program:

```
WHERE E1.Status = 'Pass'
    AND E2.Status is null or E2.Status = 'Fail'
```

This gives you the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much. Your answer completed my requirements. I tried different queries but your designed query resolved my problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: Dear, data is repeating. Actually I need the result like that:
student_id=1 exam_id=1 status = fail
student_Id=1 exam_Id=1 status = pass
student_Id =1 exam_Id=2 status = pass
then what happened ? Actually when I'll select the exam_id=2 from dropdownlist then the students should be show who passed exam_Id=1 and failure of exam_id=2 will be showing there also. Kindly give me solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query once. This will give the each student and the last exam he has taken and status

```
    SELECT student_Id
    ,Exam_Id
    ,[Status]
FROM (
    SELECT student_Id
        ,Exam_Id
        ,[Status]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY student_Id ORDER BY Exam_Id DESC
            ) [rownum]
    FROM Tbl_StudentsExamMarking
    WHERE Office_Id = 1
        AND Class_Id = 1
    ) a
WHERE a.[rownum] = 1
```

Adding the new query as per your comment.

```
DECLARE @exam_id INT = 2
SELECT
    student_Id
   ,Exam_Id
   ,[Status]
FROM Tbl_StudentsExamMarking
WHERE Office_Id = 1
AND Class_Id = 1
AND ((Exam_id = @exam_id AND [Status] = 'Fail')
   OR (Exam_id = @exam_id - 1 AND [Status] = 'Pass'))
```

Sample output for Query 1

[image]

Comment: what is row_Number in your query you use?

Comment: I need those students who passed the exam1 will be eligible for exam2 and should not be show for exam1 entry

Comment: Can you provide your sample output?

Comment: yes sure. It's showing me pass and fail students but not according to my query. if I am going to put the students for exam3 then all students should be show who passed exam2 and was fail in exam2 there should not be students who passed in exam1 etc

Comment: updated the answer with the new second query. please let me know if that is expected or you need something else?

Comment: dear, how to get only failures who not passed the exam1 till now but I don't want those who were failed in exam1 but later they passed it. so they shouldn't be shown if they passed in exam1. you can see the pic of my table: https://ibb.co/HD7yBpn

Comment: I want only who are failure till now in exam1 not those who were failed in exam1 but later they passed exam1 so they will be called as passed.

Comment: In the pic you can student_id = 10 was failed earlier but he passed the exam1 so he shouldn't be shown.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement, you said student_id = 10 is failed earlier and passed again but I don't see any records for student_id = 10 and status = Pass

Comment: let me show you https://ibb.co/KzKpDrd check this image
actually I want the list of Student_Id according to Exam_Id. See the example: I am going to enter the marks of Office_Id=1, Class_Id, and Exam_Id=2 when I'll select the Exam_Id=2 then Student_Id of those will be showing to me who passed the Exam_Id=1 and who failed in Exam_Id=2. Those students shouldn't show who passed exam_id=2 because these students are eligible for Exam_Id=3 and they passed Exam_Id=2 already.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that tests come in sequence and only depend on a single prerequisite. This isn't a recommended approach but is it the result that you need?

```
select Student_id, max(Exam_Id) as Last_Pass_Exam_Id 
from Tbl_StudentsExamMarking
where Status = 'Passed'
group by Student_id
```

Comment: no it's not result. It's returning those students who are passed in exam1 and he is eligible for exam2  but I need to show those who are fail in exam2 and eligible for exam3